# on xcode 3.2.4, are frameworks locked?

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode3.2

I just update xcode to 3.2.4 and I notice that all my frameworks has like I lock in it. Is it suppose to be like this? If not, how do I unlock them?

Here is a screen capture. One image is better than a thousand words.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a problem, or unusual. it means that you're not able to edit the files without taking a few additional measures.